# How to show the current state you are located in when using reverseGeocodeLocation in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm testing out reverseGeocodeLocation with this app that shows your closest address. I've gotten everything to work except for the showing of the current state that you are in (IL, NY, ext.). How do I do that? This is my current code:

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation)
    { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            println(error)
        }
        else
        {
            let pm = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark)

            var subThoroughtare:String = ""
            var thoroughfare:String = ""
            var subLocality:String = ""
            var subAdministrativeArea:String = ""
            var postalCode:String = ""
            var country:String = ""

            if pm.subThoroughfare != nil {subThoroughtare = pm.subThoroughfare!}
            if pm.thoroughfare != nil {thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare!}
            if pm.subLocality != nil {subLocality = pm.subLocality!}
            if pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil {subAdministrativeArea = pm.subAdministrativeArea!}
            if pm.postalCode != nil {postalCode = pm.postalCode!}
            if pm.country != nil {country = pm.country!}
            self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughtare) \(thoroughfare) \n \(subLocality) \n \(postalCode) \n \(country)"
        }
    }
```

and the output is this (example location):

```
 County Road 1760 

 79529 
 United States
```

Comment: @pjnt11, State means? whether your asking state address of the current location

Comment: I mean the state that you are currently in, as in your locations (ex. IL) @Manikandan D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for the state you want to look at the [administrativeArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLPlacemark/administrativeArea)

```
    let state = pm.administrativeArea;
```

If you look at the definition for the [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html) class it shows..

```
var administrativeArea: String! { get } // state, eg. CA
```

Comment: @pjtnt11 are you still having a problem with this?  In my testing administrativeArea is returning the state in the format you mention  (ex. IL)

Comment: Yep, its working now, thanks for both of your answers.

Comment: @RichFox How to get the full name of the state from CLLocation?